# jquery text switch

Tags: jquery, text

I am trying to make the text switch based on the image that is hovered over, but I am having some troubles, the code that I am using is:

```
$("#myImg").hover(
  function () {
    $('#myText1').css('display','inline');
    $('#myText').css('display','none');
  }, 
  function () {
    $('#myText1').css('display','none');
    $('#myText').css('display','inline');
  },
```

I am not sure why this doesn't work

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code, replace last `,` with  `)`.

Comment: also you try  $('#myText1').show() and $('#myText').hide()

Comment: Is there any reason that you are using .css as opposed to show/hide, fadeIn/fadeOut or toggle?

Comment: Well, he could use `hide()` to hide it, however if it has to be inline using `show()` will show it as a block and therefore break his layout (if it requires an inline element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should not be the final comma as this causes a syntax error.  You are also missing the closing parentheses for the call to `.hover`:

```
$("#myImg").hover(
  function () {
    $('#myText1').css('display','inline');
    $('#myText').css('display','none');
  }, 
  function () {
    $('#myText1').css('display','none');
    $('#myText').css('display','inline');
  }
);
```

It's generally better to use `.show` and `.hide` instead of using `.css` directly unless you have some reason to do so (e.g. the default display of the element is different than what you want it to be when it's shown).  The two similar ID names are also confusing.

Answer (score 0):

This small bit looks like valid js code, except for the missing ending parentheses.
How does it not work exactly, do you get any descriptive javascript errors? Having all of your code to debug would greatly help. Thanks!

Sorry, missed that I should have said the ending comma as well was bad, but downvote no needed! :C